# A floated grid with interspersed elements, thereby destroying nth-child / nth-of-type matching

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-grid

I am displaying products in a store. Each product has its own box. I want to lay the boxes out in a grid, 2 per row. However they will also be divided into categories, and so I want to put a full-width heading above each set of boxes which belong to that category. Here is my HTML:

```
    <section class="product-listing">

        <h2>Category 1</h2>

        <section>first</section>
        <section>second</section>
        <section>third</section>

        <h2>Category 2</h2>

        <section>fourth</section>
        <section>fifth</section>

        <h2>Category 3</h2>

        <section>sixth</section>
        <section>seventh</section>
        <section>eighth</section>
        <section>ninth</section>
    </section>
```

And CSS:

```
.product-listing {
    width:410px; height:100%
    background:#000;
}
.product-listing > section {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    margin:10px 10px 0 0;
    background:#ff0000;
}
.product-listing > section:nth-of-type(2n+2){
    margin-right:0;
}
```

And [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1bc5pjzb/4/)

As you can see, the grid works fine until the second h2 element is introduced, after which it falls apart, due to the 2n+2 being thrown off if the last set has an odd number of boxes. Essentially what I need to do is reset the 2n+2 formula after each heading.

Quick and dirty way would be to wrap each set of boxes in a div, but I'd rather not introduce unnecessary markup to the page if I can avoid it.

Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: flex would take care of this job :https://jsfiddle.net/1bc5pjzb/8/

Answer (score 0):

*Heads up: don't miss the end of this answer if you want to learn about the Grid Layout spec.*

One way, that only requires 1 extra element (possibly) is to wrap the entire `.product-list` element, and place the explicit width on that wrapper. That way, you can use a negative margin on the `.product-list` to account for the `section` item margin, and not worry about alternating margin declarations no matter how many elements – [JSBin example here](http://jsbin.com/xicere/1/edit?html,css,output)

```
<div class="wrap">
  <section class="product-listing">

    <h2>Category 1</h2>

    <section>first</section>
    <section>second</section>
    <section>third</section>

    <h2>Category 2</h2>

    <section>fourth</section>
    <section>fifth</section>

    <h2>Category 3</h2>

    <section>sixth</section>
    <section>seventh</section>
    <section>eighth</section>
    <section>ninth</section>
  </section>
</div>

.wrap {
  width: 410px; /* put explicit width here */
}
.product-listing {
  margin: 0 -5px; /* "expand" the .product-listing section */
}
.product-listing > section {
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  margin:10px 5px 0; /* only put equal horizontal margin on items */
  background:#ff0000;
}
.product-listing > h2 {
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 5px; /* add side margins here too */
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

The need for the extra wrapper comes from negative margins not expanding element boxes in both horizontal directions when they have an explicit width – a weird trick of the margin model.

If that doesn't work, the boring answer is probably that an extra wrapper around each collection of `section` items wouldn’t be so bad – it would allow your CSS to be much more flexible, and hardly matters for consumers of your HTML. After all, there is a number of items under each category – why not make each collection a `ul` or at least a `div` (if you feel that the list semantics are out of place)?

Finally, you *could* do this with no extra elements and the Grid Layout Module spec, but support is still experimental. Since this question is tagged with `css-grids`, I'll include that solution here for future visitors:

```
.product-listing {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* equal width columns */
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}
.product-listing h2 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

The auto layout algorithm built into the Grid spec will take care of the rest. Try the above example out in Chrome Canary (Oct 2015 – soon elsewhere too: WebKit Nightlies and Firefox are not far behind on implementing Grid). [JSBin example here](http://jsbin.com/xicere/2/edit?html,css,output).